# org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer NPE in PySpark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have following df -

```
+--------+----------+
|      Id|prediction|
+--------+----------+
|       1|       0.0|
|       2|       0.0|
|       3|       1.0|
|       4|       1.0|
|       5|       0.0|
|       6|       0.0|
|       7|       0.0|
|       8|       0.0|
|       9|       0.0|
|      10|       0.0|
+--------+----------+
```

I want to write it in csv like this -

```
Id,prediction
1,0.0
2,0.0
3,1.0
4,1.0
5,0.0
6,0.0
7,0.0
8,0.0
9,0.0
10,0.0
```

I tried like this -

```
df.write.csv('mycsv.csv')
```

But getting following error -

```
    ERROR Utils: Aborting task
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 16 more
18/01/31 17:58:55 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Job job_20180131175853_0008 aborted.
18/01/31 17:58:55 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 16 more
18/01/31 17:58:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 16 more

18/01/31 17:58:56 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/01/31 17:58:56 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:598)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 16 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Prediction.py", line 81, in <module>
    selected.write.csv('mycsv.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 766, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o211.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:188)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
    ... 16 more
```

And further more if I want to add another column `prediction2` in the same csv then what I need to do.(Suppose my df have one more column prediction2)

After appending my csv should look like this -

```
Id,prediction,prediction2
1,0.0,1.0
2,0.0,0.0
3,1.0,1.0
```

Comment: @VikasDamodar Spark 2.2

Comment: @user7348570 like he said the problem is with those functions, Can you add that also ?

Comment: @user8371915  Added complete error log. And one more thing I have dataframe with 10 columns from that I am selecting 2 columns that I want to save `selected = df.select("Id", "prediction")` and then I am trying `selected.write.csv('mycsv.csv')` this.

Comment: There is no problem in any previous function. I am getting output. Problem is coming only during saving.But my original datframe consists of some column that contain array of strings. And I am selecting only respected column that I need to write in csv. Is this error is coming because my original df consists of more columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the traceback we clearly see that the problem is unrealted to CSV writer at all:

```
caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
   at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer$$anonfun$createTransformFunc$1.apply(Tokenizer.scala:39)
```

If fails when apply `Tokenizer` transformer on a column which contains `NULL`.

Ease to reproduce example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("foo bar", ), (None, ), ("", )], ("text", ))

Tokenizer(inputCol="text").transform(df).collect()
# [Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 4) / 4]18/01/31 14:22:16 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
#   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$createTransformFunc$1: (string) => array<string>)
# ...
```

Empty strings, unless converted to `NULLs` are not an issue.

You should `na.drop`:

```
my_dataframe.na.drop(subset=["column_to_be_tokenized"])
```

before applying `Tokenizer`, i.e.

```
Tokenizer(inputCol="text").transform(df.na.drop(subset=["text"])).collect()

# [Row(text='foo bar', Tokenizer_45e4aef98611234f8c59__output=['foo', 'bar']),
#  Row(text='', Tokenizer_45e4aef98611234f8c59__output=[''])]
```

To address [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542501/write-and-append-spark-dataframe-in-csvpyspark/48543127#comment84081151_48542501):

> There is no problem in any previous function. I am getting output

Spark is lazy and unless you force full execution, will do as little work as possible (it means that `show` or `count` typically won't do).

> Problem is coming only during saving

Because this is the point where full pipeline is executed.

And to deal with the other problem `append` is not an option. You have to read data from storage, `join` with the new one, and write back.